# Vertical Meter Element HTML - Table Width

Tags: html, css

I want to create a vertical `meter` element in html. I used the following css sheet

```
meter {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 10px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

This worked perfectly fine, but when I incorporated the `meter` into a `table`, the cell took on 1000px of width instead of 10px. How should I adjust my html or css to make the table's cell properly fit the meter? IE: I want the table cell to take on the *rotated* width and height of the meter.
The html:

```
<table width="100px" cellspacing="" cellpadding="0" border="">
  <td><meter max="120" value="55.93" title="Test"></meter></td>
</table>
```

When I add a width to the table's `td` element as follows:

```
<table width="100px" cellspacing="" cellpadding="0" border="">
  <td width="10"><meter max="120" value="55.93" title="Test"></meter></td>
</table>
```

no change occurs. Input is much appreciated.

EDIT:

I solved this problem by using the `-moz-orient: vertical;` line in my meter style. This meant that the height and width were not switched and thus I could extend the height as long as I wanted without stretching the page/table.

Comment: dont put it in a table cell. The table cell is going to go by the width of the element, in this case, 1000px. You might maybe be able to give the table cell a "max-width: 10px; !important" but it may not work

Comment: @VikingBlooded this is a partial solution, but when I do this with, say, a 10,000px wide meter, the page is stretched (because the width is more than my screen can fit). How do I solve this problem more generally?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .customtd
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            display: inline-block;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        meter
        {
            width: 500px;
            height: 10px;
            transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100px" cellspacing="" cellpadding="0" border="">
        <tr>
            <td width="10px" class="customtd">
                <meter max="120" value="55.93" title="Test"></meter>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="100px" cellspacing="" cellpadding="0" border="">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <meter max="120" value="55.93" title="Test"></meter>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I found (in my opinion) a more elegant solution that I will write up.